# Why my function for users request don't working?

Tags: javascript

For a week now I can not write a function that accepts a request from the user.
Please help!

Im using node-telegram-bot-api

```
async function makeRequest(id, msg) {
            let request = ` _Your username:_ \`${msg.from.username}\`\n _Your ID:_ \`${msg.from.id}\`\n\n`
            let request_text = ``;

            const inlineKeyboard = {
                reply_markup: {
                    inline_keyboard: [
                        [{
                            text: ' Send request',
                            callback_data: 'Send'
                        }],
                    ]
                },
                parse_mode: 'Markdown',
                chat_id: msg.message.chat.id,
                message_id: msg.message.message_id,
                disable_web_page_preview: true,
            }
            
            let count = 0;
            bot.sendMessage(id, `1️⃣ *First question*`, {parse_mode: 'Markdown'})

            let handler = async (msg) => {
                let text = msg.text
                if (msg.text) {
                    count++
                    console.log(count)
                    request += `${count}) ${text}\n`
                    request_text += `${count}) ${text}\n`
                }

                if (count === 1) {
                    bot.sendMessage(id, `2️⃣ *Two question*`, {parse_mode: 'Markdown'})
                }

                if (count === 2) {
                    bot.sendMessage(id, `3️⃣ *Three question*`, {parse_mode: 'Markdown'})
                }

                if (count === 3) {
                    bot.sendMessage(id, `4️⃣ *Last question*`, {parse_mode: 'Markdown',})
                }

                if (count > 3) {
                    await bot.sendMessage(id, request, inlineKeyboard)
                    await addUserRequest(request_text, msg.from) // Save result to DB
                    bot.removeListener("text", handler); 
                }

            }

            bot.on('text', handler)
```

The user presses / start and receives a message with a button - fill out an application

When pressed, the makeRequest function is activated

Everything works when the user is alone, when many users fill out an application at the same time, nothing works

Comment: `nothing works` can you explain in terms of debugging information ...

Comment: There are no errors, it’s just that when several people fill out an application at the same time, they are in the same function, if the first one answered 1 question, then another user will receive 2 questions, and another already filled out profile is someone else’s

Comment: right, so perhaps the server side is wrong